# JSON Marshaling of composite structs which both implement MarshalJSON()

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

I faced recently the following problem and have not found any solution. I have two struct types in Go, let us call them Parent and Child. Child has an anonymous field of the type *Parent. However, Parent has a field called "ID" which has the type of a third struct which type we will call "IDType" (in my real problem this is a dialect/sql.NullInt64). IDType has an int field and a bool field.

The problem is the following: Both, Parent and Child, implement MarshalJSON() because for Parent I only want the int field inside the JSON and for Child the same. However, it seems that both MarshalJSONs infer with the result that only the values of Parent are encoded in the final JSON.

Maybe a minimal example makes it easier to understand:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type IDType struct {
    Value int
    Valid bool
}

type Parent struct {
    ID         IDType `json:"id"`
    SomeString string `json:"some_string"`
}

type Child struct {
    *Parent
    Status int `json:"status"`
}

func (parent *Parent) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias Parent
    fmt.Println("Parent")
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        *Alias
        ID int `json:"id"`
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(parent),
        ID:    parent.ID.Value,
    })
}

func (child *Child) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Alias Child
    fmt.Println("Child")
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        *Alias
        Status int `json:"status"`
    }{
        Alias:  (*Alias)(child),
        Status: child.Status,
    })
}

func main() {
    ID := IDType{Value: 1, Valid: true}
    parent := Parent{ID: ID, SomeString: "Hello"}
    child := Child{Parent: &Parent{ID: ID, SomeString: "Hello"}, Status: 1}
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(&parent)
    json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(&child)
}
```

The output is:

```
Parent
{"some_string":"Hello","id":1}
Child
Parent
{"some_string":"Hello","id":1}
```

I expect something like:

```
Parent
{"some_string":"Hello","id":1}
Child
Parent
{"some_string":"Hello","id":1, "status": 1}
```

Comment: Not sure if you've considered this, but you could declare a new type based off of `sql.NullInt64`, have it implement the MarshalJSON method together with the Scan and Value methods and use that in all your other types, then those types wouldn't have to implement the Marshaler interface.

Comment: Side note: Parent and Child have an ugly smell of traditional inheritance OOP. Maybe you should remodel your types first?

Comment: The names were just for showing my problem. In the real use case the problem was that I cannot just add a field to my SQL table because it has to be generated on the fly and is expected by the front-end on the same level as the remainder of the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you only define a custom marshaling logic because of the custom ID marshaling. Define your custom marshaling for the `IDType` type only which is not embedded, so it won't cause any trouble marshaling the other types:

```
func (id *IDType) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(id.Value)
}
```

And no other custom marshaling are required. With this, the output will be:

```
{"id":1,"some_string":"Hello"}
{"id":1,"some_string":"Hello","status":1}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZW-yVkMWbuX).

Answer (score 1):

You should either have a named pointer to parent or embeded value of Parent.

Option 1 will give you JSON you expect.

```
type Child struct {
    Parent
    Status int `json:"status"`
}
>> {"some_string":"Hello","id":1, "status": 1}
```

Option 2 will put parent as sub-node.

```
type Child struct {
    Parent *Parent
    Status int `json:"status"`
}
>> {Parent: {"some_string":"Hello","id":1}, "status": 1}
```

Another hacky option would be to marshal parent & child separately and then join manually by cutting last/first characters, join with `,` and wrap in `{}`.

Comment: For some reason Option 2 didn't worked for me. Option 2 works but the way icza has shown was what I searched for.